# Unable to return JSON response using Play Framework and Postgresql?

Tags: json, postgresql, scala, playframework

I am trying to return JSON response data from Postgresql database using Play framework(Scala).

I have tried the following where I am not able to return my json response output.

I have couple of JSON objects in my database table: `jsondata`, which is having `id` and `name`. I have written some println messages, those are coming as None, don't know why ?

The compiler error says

> Missing parameter either [id] or [name]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong in my code to get JSON response output for my JSON objects from database(controller and model).

controller:

```
import play.api.Play.current
import play.mvc.Controller;           
import play.libs.Json;
import play.libs.Json.*;                        
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;           
import models.Getjsondata
import com.google.gson.Gson
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

 Getjsondata.getJsonValues(Getjsondata(Json.parse(id)), Json.parse(name));
 class MyController extends Controller {
 def getJson = Action { request =>
    println("calling getJson ... !!")//getting this message on play console
    val body: Anyname = request.body
    val textBody: Option[String] = body.asText
    println("body: "+body);//AnyContentAsEmpty
    println("textBody: "+textBody);//None
    val optionJson = textBody.flatMap(json => Try(Json.parse(json)).toOption)
    val bodyId = optionJson.map(_ \ "id")
    val bodyname = optionJson.map(_ \ "name")
    println("bodyId: "+bodyId);//None
    println("bodyName: "+bodyName);//None
    println("optionJson: "+optionJson);//None
    {
      for {
        id <- bodyId
        name <- bodyname
        json <- optionJson
      } yield {
        println("calling getJson else ... !!")
        val response = Getjsondata.getJsonValues(Getjsondata(id.as[Long],name.as[String]));
        Ok("Json data retrieved successfully: "+response)
      }
    } getOrElse BadRequest("Missing parameter either [id] or [name]")//giving error, not executing the above for loop
  }
  }
```

model:

```
import anorm._
import anorm.SqlParser._
import play.api.db._
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.libs.json.{Json,JsValue}
import play.api.db.DB
import play.api.libs.json._
import anorm.~
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class Getjsondata (
  id: Pk[Long], name: String
)
object Getjsondata {
  val extractor = {
    get[Pk[Long]]("jsondata.id") ~
    get[String]("jsondata.name") map {
      case id~name => Getjsondata(id, name)
 }
 }
  def getJsonValues(jsondata: Getjsondata): List[Getjsondata]= {
  println("addJson getJsonValues page... !")
  DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
 // SQL("select row_to_json(jsondata) from jsondata");
    SQL("select * from jsondata");
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste full error message? including the line number, etc

Comment: @Wojtek, thanks for your reply, I have tried with println messages for bodyId, bodyContent and optionJson: it's displaying "None" for all, so that's why it is going to BadRequest message("Missing parameter either [id] or [name]"), but I have json objects(id and name) in my database table, dont' know why it's showing None for all.