# How to return json from Play Scala controller?

Tags: json, postgresql, scala, playframework, anorm

I would like to know that how can I return json response data from Play(2.2.x) Scala controller class to display on my view page ? I have json objects in Postgresql database(table name: "test" and having: id and name). Please provide me any solutions for it.

I have tried the following cases(a and b), but I am not sure why I am not getting the response(like: names) on my controller, so I can show them on my view page ? since I am very new to Play/Scala and Postgresql.
case a. If I give like:
model:

```
def getTestValuesFromTable()   =  {
  DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
  val selectJson =SQL("select name from test").on().apply().collect {  
            case Row(id:Long, Some(name:String)) => 
            new TestContent(name)
         }
         //.head
         //JsObject(selectJson().map { row => row[Long]("id").toString -> JsString(row[String]("name")) }.toSeq)
  }
  }
```

controller:

```
def getTest = Action { 
      val response = TestContent.getTestValuesFromTable()
       Ok("Done")
      //Ok(response)
   }
```

Output is: Done(application is executing fine without any exceptions, of course json data is not coming since I am returning: Done only, so  getting output: "Done")

case b. If I do like this: getting error: not enough arguments for method apply: (n: Int)models.Testname in trait LinearSeqOptimized. Unspecified value parameter n. I really not sure how can I get my response for it ?

controller:

```
def getTest = Action { 
      val response = TestContent.getTestValuesFromTable()
      // Ok("Done")
      Ok(response)
   }
```

model:

```
def getTestValuesFromTable(): JsValue = {
 DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
   val selectJson = SQL("select * from test")
    JsObject(selectJson().map { row => row[Long]("id").toString -> JsString(row[String]("name")) }.toSeq)
    // val selectJson =SQL("select name from test").on().apply().collect {  
           // case Row(id:Long, Some(name:String)) => 
           // new TestContent(name)
        // }
         //.head
    JsObject(selectJson().map { row => row[Long]("id").toString -> JsString(row[String]("name")) }.toSeq)//not enough arguments for method apply: (n: Int)models.Testname in trait LinearSeqOptimized. Unspecified value parameter n.
    }
  }
```

Please let me know how to get my response ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to return JSON response using Play Framework and Postgresql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35547677/unable-to-return-json-response-using-play-framework-and-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

`getJsonValuesFromTable` method return nothing (`Unit`). To fix it change definition of this method to

`def getJsonValuesFromTable(testContent: TestContent) = {`

or explicitly setting type:

`def getJsonValuesFromTable(testContent: TestContent): Unit = {`

Also as a next step  to let client know that you are returning json, you should set content type:

`Ok(Json.obj(response)).as("application/json")`

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have done the above thing(def getJsonValuesFromTable(testContent: TestContent) = {--} and Ok(Json.obj(response)).as("application/json")), but getting error: type mismatch; found : anorm.SqlQuery required: (String, play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper)  at: Ok(Json.obj(response)).as("application/json")

Comment: You do not actually execute query. Read how to do it with API you're using here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaAnorm

Comment: I mean I have done with the API only, written the query: select * from test; where I am doing wrong ?(how can I get json data without executing this query), please let me know. Can we have chat discussion once please ?

Comment: With `SQL(***)` you have `Stream[Row]` to transform it to actually data you have to `map` it. Double check link I gave you there are sufficient amount of details there.   Proper version: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaAnorm

Comment: I have done:   val selectJson = SQL("Select * from test")
val jsonvalues = selectJson().map(row => 
  row[Long]("id") -> row[String]("name")
).toList but still getting error: type mismatch; found : Unit required: (String, play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper)

Comment: you still had not added return type for `getJsonValuesFromTable` `=`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104262/discussion-between-dhana-and-rumoku).