# How to write Scala controller class to return JSON response?

Tags: json, postgresql, scala, playframework

I am currently learning Scala with a Play framework application (version:2.2.x).

What'd be the best way to fetch a JSON response from a postgresql database table(test)?

I have done the following trails([Unable to return JSON response using Play Framework and Postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35547677/unable-to-return-json-response-using-play-framework-and-postgresql)) and trying another approach here, but unfortunately I am unable to fetch json, and getting missing parameter type error, I am not sure whether the code is fine or not ?

controller:

```
class Test extends Controller {
implicit val testContentWrites: Writes[TestContent] = (
  (JsPath \ "id").write[Long] and
  (JsPath \ "name").write[String]
)(unlift(TestContent.unapply))

  implicit val testContentReads: Reads[TestContent] = (
  (JsPath \ "id").read[Long] and
  (JsPath \ "name").read[String]
)(TestContent.apply _)

def getTest = Action { request =>

      val response = Getjsoncontent.getJsonValuesFromTable()
          Ok(response)

 }
}
```

model:

```
case class TestContent(id: Long, name: String)
object TestContent = {
def getJsonValuesFromTable(): JsValue={
 DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
  val selectJson = SQL("select * from test")
  JsObject(selectJson().map { row => row[Long]("id").toString -> JsString(row[String]("name")) }.toSeq)//here I am getting the json data which is stored in my database on my console like as a Runtime Exception: 500 Internal Server Error
 }
}
```

Error:

```
Execution Exception:
[RuntimeException: Left(TypeDoesNotMatch(Cannot convert "{\r\n \"title\" : -------------------------------------\r\n": class org.postgresql.util.PGobject to String for column ColumnName(test.name,Some(name))))]


at line:  JsObject(selectJson().map { row => row[Long]("id").toString -> JsString(row[String]("name")) }.toSeq)
```

Comment: This question is highly broad. You should probably start with reading [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaDatabase) and [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaJson)

Comment: @hasumedic, thanks for your reply, I have modified the question description, I have tried with some code(added in description), but I am not able to fetch the response. Please let me know where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return json from Play Scala controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35573635/how-to-return-json-from-play-scala-controller)